# swf Superposition Problem

Tags: html, css, flash

My page has some swf object on html.

DespiteI'd like to swf  go to the bottom layer
the swf go to the top layer

Any solutions?

Can I swap the priolities a swf with a html element using z-index?
 want to solve a variety of environments(IE6,Firefox,Chrome...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use both z-index and wmode:

`<param name="wmode" value="transparent">` and in the embed tag `style="z-index: -1"`

Answer (score 1):

you should set window mode to transparent. Have a look here: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14201.html

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know that this mode work any environments?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but when you embed swf files you should use swfobject.js http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/